# Reset Google Colaboratory VM

Tags: virtual-machine, google-colaboratory

From https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html we can see that:

> Code is executed in a virtual machine dedicated to your account.
>   Virtual machines are recycled when idle for a while, and have a
>   maximum lifetime enforced by the system.

Installing extra packages, I kinda fucked up the virtual machine I'm currently on (playing with /etc/apt/sources.list... for example).

Is there a way to force the machine reset or recycle ?
If not, do we know the lifetime or idle time before being recycled ?

Thanks

Comment: Does the `restart runtime` option or simply disconnecting and connecting to the runtime help?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To drop your current backend and start fresh with a new one, select the command 'Reset all runtimes...' from the Runtime menu.

[image]

Comment: ...which menu option has now changed to read "Factory reset Runtime", specificially warns that all data will be lost, but currently doesn't actually change any data at all if the runtime you're using isn't a GPU backed one.

Comment: How do I do that programmatically?